# Multiple linear combinations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Lets say I have a vector $v$ and $n$ vectors $u_1,\; ... \;, u_n$

Is there a fast way to know if there are more than 1 or just 1 possibility to express $v$ as combination of $u$'s ?

The information I can use is:

- I know if $u$'s can combinate to create $v$ (that means I know if $v$ can be created with $u$'s).
- I know a vector $c$ of coeficients such that $|u_1\; ... \; u_n| *c = v$

With this information, how can I discover if there are more than one vector $w$ such that $|u_1\; ... \; u_n| *w = v$ ?

PS: $|u_1\; ... \; u_n| $ means a matrix with the vectors written vertically inside it.

Comment: Given that you know that $v$ is producible from $u_1,\ldots u_n$, you probably want to [evaluate linear independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Evaluating_linear_independence) of the vectors.

Comment: @Joffan lets say $v$ is found using $u_1,u_3, u_5$. If they all are LI (between them) then exists only one solution, otherwise infinite solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u_1\alpha_1 + u_2\alpha_2 + \dots + u_n\alpha_n = v$

iff

$\begin{bmatrix}|&|&|&&|\\
u_1&u_2&u_3&\dots&u_n\\
|&|&|&&|\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\\alpha_2\\\vdots\\\alpha_n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}|\\v\\|\end{bmatrix}$

Solve the system by setting up the associated augmented matrix:  $\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
|&|&&|&|\\
u_1&u_2&\dots&u_n&v\\
|&|&&|&|\end{array}\right]$

Row reduce and then reinterpret as a system of equations.

A row of $[0,0,\dots,0~|~1]$ will imply no solutions exist as this corresponds to the equation $0\alpha_1+0\alpha_2+\dots+0\alpha_n=1$ which is always false.

Assuming no such rows exist, a column without a leading one in the reduced row echelon form implies that infinitely many solutions exist.

If all columns have a leading one and no row of zeroes followed by a one exist, then exactly one solution exists.

---

E.g. $u_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\end{bmatrix}, u_2=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}, u_3=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}, v=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Our augmented matrix: $\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1&1&0&2\\0&1&1&1\end{array}\right]$

Row reducing: $\begin{array}{c}\color{red}{\rightarrow}\\\color{red}{\rightarrow}\end{array}\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}\color{red}{1}&0&-1&1\\0&\color{red}{1}&1&1\end{array}\right]$

We see the third column does not have any leading ones (by this I mean a pivot point, a furthest left nonzero entry in a row).  This implies that infinitely many solutions exist.  Interpreting the augmented matrix above as a system of equations:

$\begin{cases}\alpha_1-\alpha_3=1\\ \alpha_2+\alpha_3=1\end{cases}$

Letting $\alpha_3$ be any real number $t$, we have $\alpha_1 = 1+t$ and $\alpha_2=1-t$.  That is to say:

$(1+t)\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}+(1-t)\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}$ for any choice of $t\in\Bbb R$

---

Additional example:

$u_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}, u_2=\begin{bmatrix} 2\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}, u_3 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}, u_4=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\0\end{bmatrix}, v=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Set up the augmented matrix:

$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 1&2&1&1&1\\0&0&1&2&1\\0&0&0&0&1\end{array}\right]$

Row reducing:

$\begin{array}{c}\color{red}{\rightarrow}\\\color{red}{\rightarrow}\\\color{red}{\rightarrow}\end{array}\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} \color{red}1&2&0&-1&0\\0&0&\color{red}1&2&1\\0&0&0&0&\color{red}1\end{array}\right]$

Here, even though we have columns without leading ones (the second and fourth), we have a row $[0,0,0,0~ |~ 1]$, implying that no combination of those four vectors will result in $v$ (this should be clear without much work since any combination of $u_i$ will have a third component as zero, whereas $v$ has nonzero third component)

Comment: "a column without a leading one in the reduced row echelon form implies that infinitely many solutions exist.", can you just put one or two examples of this? like 3x4 or 3x5 matrices, it would help me understand

Comment: @Daniel added an example

Comment: @Daniel Note, this same method can prove the linear independence of the vectors in question.  The columns where a leading one appear correspond to the set of columns which can form a maximally independent set.  In the final example, $u_1, u_3$ and $v$ form a maximally independent set.  (So too does $u_2,u_3$ and $v$, but the method prefers building the list from left to right)

Comment: so if i find v with $u_i$ to $u_k$, there will be infinite solutions if there is linear dependence between them and only one otherwise?

Comment: @Daniel you wrote the word infinite twice.  Yes, assuming that at least one solution exists, if the $u_i$ are linearly *dependent* there will be *infinitely many* solutions, whereas if the $u_i$ are *independent* there will be exactly one solution.